# Can I deliver my software using windows update

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, software-update

Ok I would like to ship my software using windows update or similar microsoft technology to client operating systems.

I know that windows enables to provide drivers through windows update:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh833792

But I am able to prepare inf file that would install msi. Questions are:

1. Can I ship my software through windows update?
2. If I have to make a driver from it can I include msi in driver package?

Comment: Think for 2 seconds: if that were possible, your Windows would already be full of viruses and unwanted software. It would not be a viable OS. Why on earth would you want to do something like that?

Comment: Let's assume that my software has important security usages that should be included in most windows machines. It should be somehow verified by microsoft and shipped with os or should be available with windows update similar as drivers are delivered. Yes I agree - in most scenerios it would be a silly question. But in my case - i'm trying to find the best official way of how to ship my software. No reason to downvote. Please provide resources instead of your thoughts :)

Comment: Your software has "important security usages that should be included in most Windows machines"? Are you literally providing bugfixes for the operating system? How? Otherwise if your software does not modify the operating system it should never be included in operating system updates.

Comment: No - it's a little bit different. Let's assume it provides some security features to os :) Not bugfixes. To my way of thinking it could be included as soon as it is agreed with microsoft. The question still remains: how could it be included. Is there any way to ship this kind of software using windows update or similar os related mechanism?

Comment: You're putting the cart before the horse.  First you need to get Microsoft to agree to ship your software with Windows.  In the (unlikely!) event that you succeed, they'll be able to provide you with all the technical details you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like third party software that is related to driver and some hardware functionality can be pushed by windows update. This is what I have got from Microsoft - maybe it will be useful for somebody like me :)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn631786(v=vs.85).aspx

(download doc)

Answer (score 3):

Think about it. Microsoft would not let any third-party or external company install unknown (potentially dangerous) software in the name of Windows Update. If that were the case no one would buy Windows.

Only the following are acceptable to be installed with Windows Update:

- Drivers for hardware supported by Microsoft (for obvious reasons), and even these are triple-checked by the Microsoft Labs, and
- Updates by Microsoft.

Any other case would lead to catastrophic consequences for Microsoft.

I don't know what you are trying to achieve (or for what "beneficial" purpose), but it's not possible.

---

**Below are some sources from Microsoft**

Concerning Windows Update running third-party updaters, (now former) President of the Windows Division **Steven Sinofsky** [had this to say](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/b8/2011/11/14/minimizing-restarts-after-automatic-updating-in-windows-update/):

> Microsoft Update (...) offers updates for Microsoft products and for 3rd-party device drivers. All of these updates are carefully screened, and must adhere to the Windows conventions.

And goes on to justly note that:

> (...) you never know when or how updaters will run and what they might do

which is completely justified given the above reasons in this answer.

Comment: As I said in comments please provide some sources on this.

Comment: So you want to make PCs boot 100 times slower and freeze more often? You want your network connection to be fully utilized at every startup waiting for Windows to load the massive amounts of third-party software?

Comment: Provide sources. This what you said is not true - look for example at system services that are started in your system and that are not made by microsoft but are delivered with windows. Again I do not accept thoughts but facts :)

Comment: Windows does not install non-Windows system services automatically. These are installed by third-party installers, which then ask Windows to kindly start them on a regular basis. Imagine this: if your PC gets infected after a Windows Update, who's fault is it? Who is legally liable?

Comment: Actually Windows *has* often contained some third-party software.  But it's very much a "don't call us, we'll call you" situation. :-)

Comment: If you mean drivers, yes (and maybe some antivirus programs). But nothing that would make it generally possible for companies to include their software into WU. That would be a huge mistake.